# How to Change/minimize spacing between two column in ajax bar chart and how to make width of column constant in ajax,asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have ajax bar chart in which the number of columns is dynamic, can change from 1 to n columns. I want the spacing between the charts and width of the bar to be consistent. How do I fix it.    Please suggest solutions / ideas.